# How to find and replace in the bookmarked lines in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have a problem about how to find and replace in the bookmarked lines in Notepad++.

For example my line is

```
<content:encode><em>....
```

So I bookmark the lines that have `<content:encode>`, how I could find and replace  in those lines?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't.

If possible, try to enhance your **Find what** and **Replace with** expressions with condition (search expression) you used to mark your lines (**Mark** tab of **Seach** dialog). It is very likely you will need to use regular expressions. In some cases you will succeed with single **Find what/Replace with** pair, in other cases you might need multiple.